# How to install Protobuf 3.5.1 on MAC?

Tags: protocol-buffers, homebrew

How do I do that? I have brew installed, but everytime I do brew install protobuf it installs 3.6 instead. How do I get 3.5.1

Comment: You might wanna check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: i looked at all of it nothing works. protobuf used to be at 3.5.1 3 months ago but now they updated. how do i get 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew core does not support older versions of software. If you need an older version of something, you will need to use your own custom formula in a [custom tap that you maintain](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.md).

Start with the current Homebrew core formula. Copy it to your tap and stick a `@<X.Y>` at the end of its name to indicate what version it's for. Edit the file and change the `url` to point to the download for the particular version you want. Fix up the `sha256` checksum value for the new file. And change the class name in the formula file to `ProtbufAT<XY>` where  is the version number you put in the file name, with the periods removed.